Memory leak using a static unique_ptr member
I'll try to summarize the usecase as much as possible.
I have a class A (Defined in A.hpp):
class A
{
public:
   static B& getB();
private:
   A();
   static std::unique_ptr<B> m_b;
};

that uses a class B (Also defined in A.hpp)
class B
{};

In A.cpp, we define our static member A::m_b as :
std::unique_ptr<B> A::m_b = std::unique_ptr<B>(new B());

We also implemented the getB() (Also in A.cpp) method as :
B& A::getB()
{
   if (!m_b)
   {
      m_b= std::unique_ptr<B>(new B());
   }
   return *m_b;
}

I have a scenario where another static variable (call it X) is calling getB() before the initialization of the m_b variable. What is happening is the following:

getB() is being called, and m_b (still nullptr) is being initialized
to a new B().
intialization of the static variable is being called
again and m_b is being re-assigned to a new B().
The allocation done in step 1 is not being de-allocated and hence a memory leak.

Can someone please explain the memory leak? And what is the best way to solve it?

please read about [mcve]  and try to provide one. If struct B{}; is all we need to know about B then make that part of your minimal example. Dont make us assume "black boxes". The problem is somewhere in your code, the fix will be about modifying your code, to help we need to see the code

and how do you know that there is a leak? There is none in the code you show here.

Are you asking about static initialisation order? The way to fix it is to not have static members, use function statics to create singletons instead

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I know there's a leak after running ASAN which showed that the object we're creating in step 1 is not being deallocated.

@AlanBirtles Thanks for the answer. The weird thing for me is the memory leak. You are right, the code will be modified, but in the case here (although it's not the best practice), why is the memory created in step 1 not destroyed?

Is there a possibility of Static Init Order Fiasco? Is getB called in any global/static object initialiser?

As a sidenote, if you move the static into the getB function you can make this a two-liner: B& A::getB() { static std::unique_ptr<B> m_b=std::make_unique<B>(); return *m_b; }. This also prevents any other code from accessing it without going through getB.

@Yksisarvinen Indeed, getB is getting called in another static object initializer.

SIOF is undefined behaviour I think, so memory leak is quite a valid outcome. As Christian said, use Meyer's Singleton (static local variable in a function) instead.

@HusseinJaber in that case, initialization order becomes extremely important, and might not be manageable enough. Use the alternative I suggested to make it safe. Also, why unique_ptr? You could just make it a static B m_b; return m_b; ...

@Yksisarvinen  thanks for the help. Just to make sure we're aligned, SIOF means the order of initialization is undefined, but this will make the program continue working in an undefined behavior, although it's not technically wrong that the order is incorrect?

Global objects are created in top to bottom order within one file, but there is no order imposed on multiple files. If a global object requires another global object in initialisation and the other object is defined in a different file, it's pure luck if it will work or Static Init Order Fiasco happens (and it may change between compilations as well). As with all UB, it's hard to say what will happen, compiler is allowed to time travel (among other things).

@JaMiT Thanks for the comment. You're right and it's updated.

As the comments note, this indicates that A::getB is called before A::m_b is initialized. Hence, A::getB is accessing an uninitialized variable. And no, you can't fix that by then "initializing" m_b like you currently try.
Since accessing uninitialized variables is Undefined Behavior, anything can happen including memory leaks. The fix is the Meyers Singleton suggested by Christian Stieber:
B& A::getB()
{
    static B b;
    return b;
}


Since the reference is returned, unique pointer seems unnecessary overhead: static B s_b{/*init*/}; return s_b; would be similar with slightly faster initialization.
